# Any one knows of a service for billing and authenticating users of SaaS?

Tags: .net, authentication, startup, billing

I have a SaaS startup which has a windows based client interface. It is based on a freemium model and I want to take the hassle of registering, authenticating and billing customer. Any 3rd party services out there that does it?

I know of billing services, but not ones that also register and enables user authentication.

Updated:
Basically, I want users to download the app, enter their email and recieve a user/app id. Then they can add services to that account. The application needs to authenticate and check user's permissions. I want some service to take care of this entire process.

Thank you

Comment: [Stormpath](http://www.stormpath.com/) is a company providing exactly that service: user authentication, management of user accounts, password resets, and such.

Comment: [Mozilla Persona](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/persona/) enables user-authentication by having the user use existing email addresses, such as Yahoo! or Gmail, to log in to your site.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any billing apps that handle this. It's sort of two different monsters. You would have to use some kind of auth framework in conjunction with a billing app. Ours is called CheddarGetter.com.

What you probably need for the auth side of this project is a basic membership database, with some kind of access control to enhance your app's security. The most common way to do this is a combination of user/pass security and session control. IP screening is also possible, but usually not pragmatic.

There are plenty of frameworks that include some kind of user/auth goodness. I'm not sure about .net, but here are a few other flavored options:

Rails:
https://github.com/RailsApps/rails3-mongoid-omniauth
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

PHP:
http://framework.zend.com/